# How can I rename all files inside a folder with spaces inside a variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that renames files inside a folder. Each one has the same naming format: `car error file (1).txt`.

How can I remove the spaces from the title? I have to replace all spaces, tab and similars chars from each file and replace them with a jolly char (`|`) so I can take a string from each of the files.

The error that I have is that the batch file tries to find the file with only the name `car` and obviously it doesn't exist.

The `old` name doesn't need to be saved for after, so they can all be called car1, car2 and so on.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET dir=C:\Users\betacom\Desktop\file\pat\SEMPREALAMENTARSEOH\

echo.>Output.csv

for /f %%f in ('dir /b %dir%*.txt') do (
    ::rename %%f "something.txt"
)

for /f %%f in ('dir /b %dir%*.txt') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr \.edi %dir%%%f') do echo(%%a;;%%f)>>Output.csv

::after this row above will be:
    REM for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %%a in ('findstr \.edi %dir%%%f') do echo(%%a;;%%f)>>%dir%Output.csv

)
```

current file names:

> car error file (1).txt
>   car error file (2).txt
>   ...

what I need them to be:

> car1.txt
>   car2.txt
>   ...

Comment: For starters, you'll need to put `%%f` in parentheses so your `rename` command won't cut it off at "car". Beyond that - I'm not sure if you're approaching the problem the easiest way... is your end goal to remove `error file ()` from `car error file (1)` so that it's `car1` as your desired output states? or what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: well actually the name doesn't need to be something particular, i just want to cycle into the folder to extract a string, the second part i think i got it, but i can't do the first part. 
If you mean like `rename (%%f) car.txt` I just tryed but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: just realized my comment said "`%%f` in parentheses` instead of "`%%f` in quotes" - that's why it was cutting off at car. what string are you trying to extract with your loop?

Comment: exactly which `%%f` do i have to quote? because it could be neat if i can use just the second for to do it. Btw i've tryed it on the first for but still doesn't work.

Can you please post the part of the code i have to modify? thx

Comment: basically i have around 300 files converted from .msg to .txt, they are all similar. They all have a string between two tab chars. i can find the row by using `findstr \.edi` (tested by renaming manually 1 file removing spaces), than i'll remove the spaces replacing with the pipe char and then i'll extract it to the .csv file. I know that i can skip the replace step but i'm not quite sure how can i identify the tab char (maybe `tokens=2 delims=\t`?)

Comment: space and tab are both delimiters in `for` loops by default; I would definitely skip that "replacing spaces with the pipe char" part as that `|` would need to be escaped pretty much everywhere your variable would be used - which is another reason it might be cutting off at "car".

Answer (score 0):

As requested:

```
@echo off

set "dir=C:\Users\betacom\Desktop\file\pat\SEMPREALAMENTARSEOH"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%A in ('dir /b %dir%\*.txt') do (
    rename "%%A" "%%~nA something.txt"
    set "var=%%~nxA"
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ('findstr \.edi %dir%\!var!') do (
        echo(%%B;;%%A)>>Output.csv
        echo(%%B;;%%A)>>%dir%\Output.csv
    )
)
```

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I've restructured the `for` loop to make a bit more sense. For example, there's no need to have separate loops with the same `for` options when all you're changing is the `do` commands - so I've nested the loops and added multiple `do` lines when applicable.

I changed some stuff based on personal preference to show how it's easier to follow your logic if you start with `%%A` and sequentially go through the alphabet when introducing new parameters (`%%A`, `%%B`, `%%C`, etc.) - that way you know `%%B` is your second/nested parameter without having to go back and look at anything; it's also good to avoid lowercase letters in your parameters since some of them correlate to parameter extensions.

As we talked about in the comments - any time you're handling variables in commands (other than `echo` and some other circumstances), you're pretty much always going to want them within quotes so potential spaces aren't going to throw you off. If your variable inherits a special character that would otherwise need to be escaped in an individual command or in batch as a whole, you'll need to address that prior to using the variable elsewhere.

Reference: [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [Parameters / Arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Comment: i'm a beginner that never studied the teory of batch programming too much, just learning with "experience", but can you tell what `%%~nxA` does? and also why is there a space between it and `something.txt`?

Comment: `%%~nxA` reduces parameter `%%A` to just the file name (`n`) and extension (`x`) - you can see more of those by going to the "Parameters / Arguments" link in my reference section. You were renaming all your files "something.txt", which is going to give you issues after the first loop - so I included the name of the file with a space and "something". I'll remove the `x` from that line specifically, but ultimately it doesn't matter since the goal was just to make sure the name is different every loop (if the names of the files don't repeat).

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
:again
SET /a processed=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*car*" ' ) DO (
 rem for each filename matching mask...
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=() " %%p IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%q" neq "" (
  rem here for filenames containing at least 1 of the delimiter set to be eliminated
  rem try to create a new filename containing not-banned characters
  SET /a processed+=1
  SET "changedthisname="
  FOR %%r IN ("" _ $ x q j %random%) DO IF NOT DEFINED changedthisname (
   IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%p%%~r%%q" REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%p%%~r%%q"&SET "changedthisname=y"
  )
 )
)
ECHO namechange attempts=%processed%%
IF %processed% gtr 0 GOTO again
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

Since you appear to not care about the new filename, provided it does not contain the characters you wish to eliminate, perhaps this will do your task.

The outer loop looks for any filename containing `car` and assigns the name in its entirety to `%%a`.

The next loop analyses the name and splits it into two portions - that before and that after any of the unwanted characters (set up in the `delims=`). If the filename has none of the unwanted characters, then the second portion of the filename in `%%q` will be empty, so we can ignore them. Otherwise, we try to substitute other allowed characters for those being disallowed. I chose `""` (empty string - just drop the characters) , `_`, `$`, `x`, `q`, `j` (as they are rare) or a random number. `changedthisname` keeps track of whether the file has been renamed so that the process does not attempt multiple renames of the same file.

`processed` counts the filenames that had the unwanted characters in any pass, so at the end of the pass, if none were found we're finished.

So a filename like `car error file (1).txt` using `()[space]` as delimiters for `%%p` may process the name to `car$error file (1).txt` on the first pass, `car$error_file (1).txt`, `car$error_filej1).txt` on the third and `car$error_filej19162.txt` on the fourth.

Well, OK - the change-the-name-to section is a little complicated and could be persuaded to be `car`+a random number - but hey, computers are complicated and a simple random number would be - well, no fun at all.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but it is just too complex for me ahahah. But there is a thing that you can still help me with. 

At the moment I have this, the processed variable remains at 2 and doesn't increment. Can you tell me why and how to fix this?

`SET /a processed=2

for /f %%f in ('dir /b %dir%*.txt') do (
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr \.edi %dir%%%f') do echo("=STRINGA.ESTRAI(E%processed%;10;TROVA("".edi"";E%processed%)-5)";;;;%%a)>>Output.csv
 SET /a processed+=1
)  
`

Comment: Depends substantially on how you display the changed value. Within the loop, using `echo %processed%` will display the *original* value of `processed`. You could consult the many SO articles about `delayed expansion` to see more. If you are using `processed` for some other task, then you will probably need to invoke `delayed expansion` mode or call a subroutine. If you are simply displaying the value, try `call echo %%processed%%`